# Live search en selectpicker de bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy utilizando bootstrap 4 en una aplicación y necesito implementar una búsqueda en algunos de los select.

Esta es la forma en la que están los select:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="mySelect1">
    <option value="0">No Selected</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

He intentado hacerlo con varios plugins como [**`bootstrap-select`**](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) pero solo funcionan con bootstrap 3 y no puedo encontrar una forma de hacerlo con bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

necesitas incluir el siguiente codigo en un estilo

```css
/*
Make bootstrap-select work with bootstrap 4 see:
https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1135
*/
.dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #292b2c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #303f9f;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
.dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover{
  color: #292b2c;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #303f9f;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.bootstrap-select.show>.dropdown-menu>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-menu li.hidden{
  display:none;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-menu li a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 1.5rem;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #292b2c;
  text-align: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: 0 0;
  border: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu > li.active > a {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #3f51b5 !important;
}

.bootstrap-select .check-mark::after {
  content: "✓";
}
.bootstrap-select button {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* Make filled out selects be the same size as empty selects */
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-toggle .filter-option {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Recomendaria que hicieras una breve explicacion de lo que hace tu codigo